# Fill combobox with list<object> items

Tags: c#, list, combobox

So I made this class to get frequencies of a given string:Gender from a List ->

```
public static List<GenderFrequency> GenderFrequencies(List<Bird> birds)
{
    List<GenderFrequency> result = new List<GenderFrequency>();
    foreach (Bird b in birds)
        UpdateGenderList(b, result);
    return result;
}

private static void UpdateGenderList(Bird b, List<GenderFrequency> freqs)
{
    foreach (GenderFrequency freq in freqs)
        if (freq.Gender.Equals(b.Gender, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            freq.FrequencyPlus1();
            return;
        }
    GenderFrequency newfr = new GenderFrequency() { Gender = b.Gender, Frequency = 1 };
    freqs.Add(newfr);
    //Console.WriteLine(newfr);

}

private void FrequencyPlus1()
{
    Frequency = Frequency + 1;
}
public override string ToString()
{
    return Gender + " (" + Frequency + ")";
}
```

And I want to put those results in a combobox using this method:

```
 private void showGenderFreq()
        {
            cboGenderFreq.Items.Clear();
            foreach (GenderFrequency g in GenderFrequency.GenderFrequencies())
            {
                cboGenderFreq.Items.Add(g);
            }

        }
```

But it gives me an error because I don't know what list parameter to put into Genderfrequencies() to make it work, VS then sugested to add this code to my Genderfrequency class:

```
 internal static IEnumerable<GenderFrequency> GenderFrequencies()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But I don't think it's much help, the problem is probably somewhere in showGenderFreq()

thank you in advance

Comment: In which type (class ) do you have the definition of your static method `public static List<GenderFrequency> GenderFrequencies(List<Bird> birds)` ?

Comment: it's in the class GenderFrequency

Comment: so why don't you use it ? You just need to add a list of birds  as parameter `foreach (var g in GenderFrequency.GenderFrequencies(myListOfBirds))` would be alright. Or can you have a GenderFrequency List without passing a List of Birds ?

Comment: Compiler looks for an argument to be passed into `GenderFrequencies` method execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GenderFrequencies` method is defined as needing a parameter (`List<Bird>`), and you don't supply that.  You need to supply the parameter:

```
foreach (GenderFrequency g in GenderFrequency.GenderFrequencies(birds))
```

where `birds` would be a (theoretically) defined `List<Bird>` object.

However, I would get the List returned from `GenderFrequencies` in a temporary variable and then iterate through that temporary variable, rather than calling `GenderFrequencies` each time through the loop.  Something like this:

```
List<GenderFrequency> genderFrequencies = GenderFrequencies.GenderFrequencies(birds);

foreach (GenderFrequency g in genderFrequencies)
{

}
```

Also, I would make a couple of small changes to your program for readability.

First, change your static `GenderFrequencies` method to something like `GetGenderFrequencies`.  It's more descriptive (in my opinion).

Secondly, the `GenderFrequencyPlus1` method could be replaced with a simple `Frequency++;`.

So it could look something like this:

```
foreach (GenderFrequency freq in freqs)
{
    if (freq.Gender.Equals(b.Gender, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        freq.Frequency++;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works when I directly ref to the .csv filehandler for my list of birds, but is there another way to call upon my own generated list of Bird Objects?
`GenderFrequencies(List<Birds> birds)` is not working for me

Comment: @user2740565 - I'm not sure what you mean.  You can create your own list of birds and pass it in - how is not working for you?  Do you get an error?